# Web Service HTTP PUT json request body vb

Tags: json, vb.net

```
PUT .../jobs/expenses/3434534534 HTTP/1.1 
Host: ....com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 251
Accept: application/json
Origin: .....com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,       like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36
Authorization: N/A
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: .....
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: .....

{"amount": 0, "timein": "11:11", "timeout": "12:11".....}
```

I have been working on getting this json body that is being sent (viewed with fiddler) but I am always getting an empty string.

Setting the following:  HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream.Position = 0 before trying to read the information still returns an empty string.

Various ways I've tried to extract this information

```
Dim myStream As Stream
myStream = HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream
myStream.Position = 0
Dim myStreamReader As New StreamReader(myStream)
otherText = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd()


Dim bytes = New Byte(objRequest.InputStream.Length - 1) {}
objRequest.InputStream.Position = 0
objRequest.InputStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
otherText = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes)
```

How can I pull this information that I can view with fiddler, all avenues that I have explored has resulted with the same results.  Empty string.